# i want to build docker image in gitlab-runner by docker container use shell executor

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use docker to run gitlab-runner, and i register gitlab-runner as shell executor,
I want to build docker image, but failed, the error is docker command is not found.
[image]

Comment: Please share your CI script code. Aside from that, what image are you using? Have you tried DinD?

Comment: hi,i don't use docker image,i want to build a docker image with shell executor,the gitlab-runner is running in docker container